# How to use same layout for different actions in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am designing an app which contains around 25 questions.

How to keep changing the questions when i click the next button.
So here the layout remains the same except the question (i.e. the `TextView` may change according to different questions but other elements like `Buttons`, background will not change).So creating many  layout for different questions is time consuming.

So how can I use the same `layout` for these many questions.Should I create these many `layouts and classes` for asking each question??

Comment: Modify `TextView`s programmatically, in the `onCreate()` of  your desired `Activity`.

Comment: `Should i create these many layouts and classes for asking each question?` Obviously **not**. Reuse what you already have, as much as you can. `Be green, recycle!`

Answer (score 1):

You should store your questions in a database, or in a `static final String[]` if there aren't many of them.

Multiple classes are not required here, because you only change the question text, i.e. `questionView.setText(newQuestion);`.

Then you need 2 buttons - yes and no, which have an `OnClickListener` set to them, which in return sets the `questionView`'s text with the `newQuestion`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which will extend `Fragment`. Use your standard layout inside `onCreateView`.

Create a method inside this class like this:

```
public static FragmentName newInstance(int question)
{
    FragmentName fragment = new FragmentName();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("QUESTION_ID", question);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now inside your fragment's `onCreateView` method add some code to check the question number and edit the layout as needed

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    /* ... Code to inflate your layout ... */
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    int question = arguments.getInt("QUESTION_ID", 0);
    switch(question)
    {
        /* Add your code in here to modify the layout */
    }
    /*... ....*/
}
```

Now just use a `fragment manager` from your activity to handle the transitions, using `FragmentName.newInstance(question_number)` to instantiate the single fragments.

This is of course if just programmatically editing the Views from inside the Activity is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Create different `classes` but use the same `layout` for every class. and show/hide required `textviews` in each class.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have parent layout which contain item(Parent view of question just like view container) and resolve it after that infalte your question layout by using this code. and replace the just values on the `OnClickListener` of yes button.

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
// Access chile view by child.getElementById(id)
item.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click yes or no change the textview content accrodingly;

```
 yes_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {

            tv_question.setText("This is a new question");.

        } 

    });
```